# Cartesian Coordinate Smoothing With C#

Tags: c#, math, rfid

we are trying to develop an application with RFID readers and using speedway readers so i'm using octane sdk. when we get coordinates from each tag, we need to calculate coordinates. But sometimes we get wrong coordinates and we have to recalculate.

For this calculation, i need an algorithm which is filtering and correcting the multiple points(array of x-y). it should calculate wrong coordiantes with correct coordinates.

I've searched lots of algorithm like kalman, least squares, levenberg-marquardt but i think the problem is i don't have any model for tags and i can't fit any value to it.

I know for this case i have to apply some mathematics but i can't find.

Comment: Maybe, since this is more a mathematic question than a programming one, you can try on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "sometimes we get wrong coordinates and we have to recalculate" - that's not very specific. You'll need to describe and illustrate the problem, show us what you get and what you want.

Comment: As you pose the question, you will only get answers from someone with nearly exactly the same problem. If you tell us what geometric data you get from the readers, then this may reduce to a wider understood triangulation problem.

Comment: @MartinVerjans yes i totally agree to you. i can try out. thanks

Comment: @Chris i have three readers(Reader1, Reader2, Reader3) and i have four tags.
same tag could be read from multiple readers and im calculating coordinates of tag. just an example like this;


Tag1 reported by Reader1. Coordinates are 1200(x) and 1400(y) -> might be true
Tag1 reported by Reader2. Coordiantes are 1280(x) and 1436(y) -> might be true
Tag8 reported by Reader2. Coordinates are 600(x) and -600(y) -> this is wrong coordinate because reflection.
Tag20 reported by Reader3. Coordinates are 2361(x) and -3499(y) -> might be true.

Comment: @Chris 

so actualy i cannot avoid reflection with readers and i have to do this by calculating. thats what i need. im looking for an algorithm for calculate coordinates it may be true.

Comment: How do you know that some coordinates might be true while others might not? Are all coordinates in the same systems or do the readers have their own coordinate systems?